# Symfony elasticsearch 2 words query not results

Tags: symfony, elasticsearch

I want to filter elasticsearch for Brands, but the problem is, if I search one word in a term it works, but if I search two words, it returns 0. The example query:

**Returns 0 records (And 1 exists)**

```
array:2 [▼
  "size" => 9999
  "query" => array:1 [▼
    "bool" => array:2 [▼
      "must_not" => array:1 [▼
        "range" => array:1 [▼
          "price" => array:1 [▼
            "lte" => 0
          ]
        ]
      ]
      "must" => array:2 [▼
        0 => array:1 [▼
          "query_string" => array:1 [▼
            "query" => "caldera"
          ]
        ]
        1 => array:1 [▼
          "terms" => array:1 [▼
            "brand" => array:1 [▼
              0 => "material comun"
            ]
          ]
        ]
      ]
    ]
  ]
]
```

**And with one word returns 2 results (Correct)**

```
array:2 [▼
  "size" => 9999
  "query" => array:1 [▼
    "bool" => array:2 [▼
      "must_not" => array:1 [▼
        "range" => array:1 [▼
          "price" => array:1 [▼
            "lte" => 0
          ]
        ]
      ]
      "must" => array:2 [▼
        0 => array:1 [▼
          "query_string" => array:1 [▼
            "query" => "caldera"
          ]
        ]
        1 => array:1 [▼
          "terms" => array:1 [▼
            "brand" => array:1 [▼
              0 => "tifell"
            ]
          ]
        ]
      ]
    ]
  ]
]
```

**EDIT**

But when I search for URI it works:

> _search?q=brand:MATERIAL+COMUN

Comment: try to add \ before the space

Comment: you need an exact match with a terms query. Is the brand name "MATERIAL COMUN"  ?

Comment: @DanDumitriu if I search with URL it works with spaces, but with that query no :S

Comment: @PierreMallet yes